# How do I configure 'proximity to address' exposed view filter?

Tags: views, 8, location

I have a view of nodes each with an address, and latitude/longitude. I've attached a Google Maps view block which displays the pins on the map corresponding to the results in the list.

I'm using geocoder to convert address module addresses to a lat/long field on node save, and geolocation for the map and proximity search. I can use lat/long and distance for proximity search, but I'd like the users to enter an address and see the results sorted by distance.

It seems like all the functionality is in place, it just needs wiring together. How can I set up an exposed filter to accept an address, maybe convert it to lat/long behind the scenes, and use a very large default distance to display the results by proximity?